# PHP script with systemd

Tags: php, systemd, daemon

I'm new to systemd and I've got issue with script my colleague gave me. This script worked as background process in Debian 7 but doesn't in Debian 8. I decided to rewrite it to systemd.

I have this in `chunk8.service` (which is located in `/etc/systemd/system`):

```
[Unit]
Description=Chunk-search Daemon
Requires=mysql.service apache2.service

[Service]
PIDFile=/var/run/chunkrm8.pid
ExecStart=/usr/bin/php /var/www/chunkrm8/task_pool.php > /dev/null 2>/dev/null
Type=forking
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I reboot the system (or run `systemctl start chunk8.service`) I get:

```
● chunk8.service - Chunk-search Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/chunk8.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Tue 2016-04-19 16:21:20 MSK; 1min 1s ago
```

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `systemctl status chunk8.service` return? When you run `/usr/bin/php /var/www/chunkrm8/task_pool.php > /dev/null 2>/dev/null` (or `sudo /usr/bin/php /var/www/chunkrm8/task_pool.php > /dev/null 2>/dev/null`) does your terminal return, or does it sit there spitting out logs and details for the service?

Comment: I've changed Type and now I'm getting:

`root@debian84:~# systemctl status chunk8.service`
`● chunk8.service - Chunk-search Daemon`
 `Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/chunk8.service; enabled)`
 `Active: active (running) since Wed 2016-04-20 11:24:03 MSK; 2s ago`
 `Main PID: 4116 (php)``CGroup: /system.slice/chunk8.service`
 `└─4116 /usr/bin/php /var/www/chunkrm8/task_pool.php > /dev/null 2>/dev/null`

But stopping is still an issue.

Answer (score 6):

You specified `Type=forking` but the program you started never forked within the timeout period, so systemd considered that it hadn't started up properly, killed it, and marked the service as failed.

Are you sure that your process daemonizes itself? It would be quite unusual for a PHP script to do this. Perhaps you should be using `Type=simple` instead.

Comment: It helped with start but I still have problem with stopping. It takes too long and I've got these lines with journalctl -xn:
`systemd[1]: chunk8.service stop-sigterm timed out. Killing.
systemd[1]: chunk8.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
systemd[1]: Unit chunk8.service entered failed state.`